# AWS Lambda: pausing a function seems to take several minutes to take effect

Tags: aws-lambda

I paused a CloudWatch trigger to a Lambda function.

There is just 1 invocation of this Lambda function which runs every minute.

However, for the next 10 minutes it would keep executing.

Any suggestions why?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling CloudWatch event rule should prevent Lambda invocation immediately. You can find out what triggers are attached to your Lambda by expanding **Designer** tab. You should see the CloudWatch Events trigger appearing enabled but as long as this is the only trigger it should be fine. You may also want to console log event and context to further investigate it in the CloudWatch logs.